# Kendo UI Grid Hide Column.Template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

The components I'm using Kendo UI, but I have problem in Grid

If you use the code below the column "Command" does not show on the page, but the page Change Sort or by grid, there is a page refresh.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.cd_empresa).Visible(false);
    columns.Bound(p => p.cd_grupo).Visible(false);
    columns.Bound(p => p.descricao);
    columns.Template
    (
        @<text>
    Text 1
    Text 2

    </text>
    ).Title("Command").Width(80);

})
.ColumnMenu()
 .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(240))
.Filterable()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .PageSize(7)
    .Read(read => read.Action("Index", "GrupoFiscal"))
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.cd_grupo))
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.cd_empresa))
)
```

)

If I put

```
. DataSource (dataSource => dataSource
         . Ajax ()
         . ServerOperation (false)
         . PageSize (7)
         . Read (read => read.Action ("Index", "GrupoFiscal"))
         . Model (model => model.Id (p => p.cd_grupo))
         . Model (model => model.Id (p => p.cd_empresa))
     )
```

Ajax works without refresh the page, but the column "Command" no shows.
Note This column has links to Edit, Delete and Details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/troubleshooting#a-column-template-is-not-displayed):

> A column template is not displayed
>
> This will happen if the server template is set but the grid is
>   configured for ajax binding. Set the ClientTemplate as well. This will
>   also happen if only the client template is set but the grid is
>   configured for server binding. Set the Template as well.